# (Xcode) std::stoi and std::to_string c++11 functions not recognized

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11

I'm running Xcode 5.0 (5A1413) on Mac OSX 10.9.2.  It is using default compiler of LLVM 5.0. I'm seeing the following errors when trying to build my project wherever `std::to_string` or `std::stoi` are used:

> No member 'to_string' in namespace std
>
> No member 'stoi' in namespace std. Did you mean atoi?

I did search stackoverflow and found some posts regarding these functions dependency on c++11.  Therefore in my Xcode settings, my build settings are as follows:

Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language Settings:

- C Language Dialect = "c11"
- C++ Language Dialect = "C++11[-std=c++11]"
- C++ Standard Library = "libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)"

I have also tried setting C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library respectively to Default.  Results are the same.

I checked my toolchain.  When I run `xcode-select -p`

I get:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Complete toolchain path is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1

The "string" defined in the toolchain subdirectory does have `stoi` and `to_string` function prototypes.  So it seems that I'm pointing to the right toolchain.  Obviously I'm missing something here.

Would be grateful for any help in solving this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`? And can you get XCode to show you the command line it uses to invoke the compiler?

Comment: Did you include the header file? Why don't you show us your code?

Comment: @Praetorian  How do I get XCode to show me the command line it uses to invoke the compiler?  Strangely, having '#include <string>' didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I have no idea, never used XCode.

Comment: @AndreyErick The problem areas are just one-liners that are interspersed throughout a rather large code file so it seemed more efficient to just show the lines.  For example 'command += std::to_string(port);' where port is a uint16_t.  Or 'cseq = std::stoi(param);' where param is a 'string'.

Comment: Are you sure your file is a .cpp file and is being compiled as c++? If you click the "Report" navigator, it will show the build runs it's done and you can navigate down to see the full compiler invocations. Alternatively, you could run xcodebuild from the command line and see it too.